# Unable to display iframe body with srcdoc attribute in Internet Explorer

Tags: javascript, html, angular

I am trying to bind the iFrame from a API response to div with id. It is not working in IE. I am able to bind the iframe, but iframe is not displaying the raw HTML:

.html file

```
<div id="div" ></div>
```

.ts file

```
theIframe = "<iframe srcdoc=\"&lt;!DOCTYPE html&gt;\n&lt;html&gt;\n    &lt;head&gt;\n        &lt;script src=&quot;https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js&quot; type=&quot;text/javascript&quot;&gt;&lt;/script&gt;\n        &lt;width=\"100%\" height=\"600px\" scrolling=\"no\" frameborder=\"0\"></iframe>"

document.getElementById('div').innerHTML = theIframe;
```

Answer (score 0):

A working and better way would be to write to the IFRAME via JS:

```
<div id="target"></div>
<script>
document.getElementById("target").innerHTML = "<iframe id=\"my-frame\" src=\"about:blank\"></iframe>";
var frame = document.getElementById("my-frame");
var fdoc = frame.contentDocument;
fdoc.write("<!doctype html><head></head><body>Here is some content.</body></html>");
</script>
```

Please note that this will work in Firefox and Chrome, Internet Explorer will most likely prompt an ActiveX security popup that would need to be accepted by the user.

---

**Using `srcdoc`**

You don't need to (better said: you are not allowed to) to escape the HTML characters in `srcdoc` as this will tell the browser to render the characters "<" or ">" rather than interpreting them as begin and end of a tag. You will need to decode/unescape them before (I used [Wladimir's answer from another SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34064434/1178759) to handle the decoding) and then make sure that you convert the quotes to single quotes. Also make sure that the response of the API returns proper HTML as what you posted in your comment is incomplete and the double quote sign is missing in the `srcdoc` tag.

```js
function htmlDecode(input) {
  var doc = new DOMParser().parseFromString(input, "text/html");
  return doc.documentElement.textContent;
}

let div = document.getElementById("div");
let response = '&lt;!DOCTYPE html&gt;\n&lt;html&gt;\n &lt;head&gt;\n &lt;script src=&quot;code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js&quot; type=&quot;text/javascript&quot;&gt;&lt;/script&gt;\n&lt;head&gt;&lt;body&gt;Some content.&lt;/body&gt;&lt;html&gt;';
div.innerHTML = "<iframe src=\"about:blank\" srcdoc=\"" + htmlDecode(response).replace(/"/g, "'") +"\"></iframe>";
```

```html
<div id="div">

</div>
```

Comment: Iframe that I was trying to bind is API response. Likely be "<iframe srcdoc=\"&lt;!DOCTYPE html&gt;\n&lt;html&gt;\n    &lt;head&gt;\n        &lt;script src=&quot;https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js&quot; type=&quot;text/javascript&quot;&gt;&lt;/script&gt;\n        &lt;width=\"100%\" height=\"600px\" scrolling=\"no\" frameborder=\"0\"></iframe>". 
Able to bind the Iframe but the body of Iframe is not displayed. Showing empty body

Comment: @KURRUHEM just added another version which should fit.